# Live input to neutral out capacitor purpose in UPS

Tags: capacitor, ups

My UPS has a flat capacitor from live input to neutral output. Can I remove this? It works without it anyway.

Q. What is the purpose?

Comment: Why do you want to modify a product that has safety ratings, without seemingly any improvement in mind? You basically want to take out parts that are "not needed". If they were not needed, they would likely not be there... Not a great idea at all.

Comment: `Can I remove this?` If you want your equipment to get damaged when there are some spikes on your grid then yes, why not? Can be a good experiment, though, to see why any component shouldn't be removed from an already-working-well device.

Comment: thing is the solder failed and, soldering back require precision in tight space

Answer (score 4):

It’s probably not a capacitor, but a transient voltage suppressor (TVS). It’s likely the MOV (metallic oxide varistor) type. Its purpose is to catch and dissipate high-voltage spikes that can damage the power supply primary side.

Your power supply can work without it, but it will be more susceptible to transient spikes on the line, so better to keep it, or if it’s damaged, replace it.

Common vendors for these include Panasonic, TDK, Littelfuse.

If the MOV is fried, probably other things downstream are damaged too, like the input filter caps. Check those for signs of stress, like leaks or bulging out. Replace any bad ones with the *exact* same type: they need to be safety certified and have adequate temperature range and electrical performance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a capacitor it is there to suppress high frequency noise that occurs as a voltage between the output wires and mains AC input. The noise problem is real and common in high frequency switching based power supplies. Your device very likely is one, no matter it has also DC to AC conversion.

If you remove the capacitor everything connected to the output starts to behave as noise emitting antenna. It stops to obey EMI regulation limits. Radio communication nearby will suffer (radio, tv, wireless networking) and directly connected devices can catch so much noise that their operation is unreliable.

Not asked: That capacitor should be Y-rated type, because it bypasses insulation between mains AC line and touchable parts. A common drawback of the capacitor is the slight, but easy to detect mains AC leakage to the metal parts of the connected devices.